# jQuery - wait half second between specific steps inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this function:

```
function selectkontakt(z){
        $("#loadnew").empty();
        $("#loadold").empty();
        // I need half second pause here before it goes on
        kontakte();
        $("#textarea").show();
    }
```

In the comment you can see where I need a half second pause before it goes on, is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a timeout

```
function selectkontakt(z){
    $("#loadnew").empty();
    $("#loadold").empty();
    setTimeout(function() {
        kontakte();
        $("#textarea").show();
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Ok nice thanks, I allready tried setTimeout but didn't rly know how to use it properly :D